# Is this correct usage of the word room?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

My friend was facing some hardships due to this pandemic and I texted her that she can reach out to me anytime if she wants someone to talk and she replied with "Thanks for providing me this room". I was confused at first because there is no "room" per se. But on further clarification she meant that she's grateful for me being emotionally present for her. Now, my question is whether this is correct or incorrect usage of the word room?

Comment: Room = space. For example "room to breathe", or "is there room for me (in your car)?" The usage is unusual but not incorrect.

Comment: And 'space' ≈ time to come round, find one's feet.

Comment: Room is freedom, too. *Give me some space here, Man*. Your invitation gives her the freedom to return for comfort.

Comment: I'm aware of the other meaning. I was only asking about the grammatical correctness of this statement. I would have had a similar doubt if "space" was used here instead of "room", in which case I would have asked: shouldn't it be "thanks for giving me space" than "thanks for giving me the/this space".